# How to convert Base64 image as a result from barcode scanner?

Tags: android, kotlin, zxing

I am trying to decode info from barcode (PDF_417) which contain Base64 image in return (I am using Zxing library for reading barcodes) I have found how to convert Base64 string to Image which can be placed in imageView, but it still returns me nothing and says that `Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'`

My code:

```kotlin
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val result: IntentResult? = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (result != null) {
            val barcodeValue = result.content
            if (barcodeValue != null) {
                val imageBytes = Base64.decode(barcodeValue, Base64.DEFAULT)
                val decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
                val intent = Intent(this, BarcodeScanner::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("image", decodedImage)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
               Sysytem.out.println("Can't handle")
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
```

Second screen where I want decoded image will appear:

```kotlin
    class BarcodeScanner : AppCompatActivity()  {
    
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.barcode_layout)
            val  barcodeImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img)
            val barcodeValue = intent.getStringExtra("barcodeValue")
           barcodeImage.setImage(barcodeValue )
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: PDF417 doesn't generally hold image data.  There's no enough storage space there.  It can hold a place to find an image, like a small URL.  But the maximum size is only 1108 bytes, there's not enough room for more than a tiny picture in that.

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray return Bitmap.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int).
convert Bitmap to Bytearray and move to another activity in bundle

Comment: thanks to @GabeSechan for his hint, bacause barcode  did not contain an image - it was a long string encoded in base64